# Accidentally deleted settings from H2 console. How to retrieve them

Tags: h2

I am not able to find Generic H2(Server) setting on the console. I accidentally removed it.

I tried finding the .h2.server.properties file on Mac but wasn't able to find the file

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Did you look in the user home directory?

Comment: I tried finding in the user home directory, but couldn't find the file

Answer (score 2):

With **h2 server stopped**, open terminal, **make sure that you are in your user directory** (~) and delete with `rm .h2.server.properties` that hidden file and on your next start of h2 it will be recreated with the default contents of all example connections.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the same situation, and it was a simple solution
The file was hidden file, so you can enable to show it